# beamer minted different top offset

Tags: beamer, minted

Unfortunately, there is different behaviour on debian 9 and ubuntu 16.04 for minted combined with beamer. It is not the generation of the code (that is identical, i checked) but the layout. I had a couple of issues, even an error, but I boiled it down to a very simple example showing that the debian version has an increased top offset, which obviously disturbs everything.

This is the code

```
\documentclass[10pt,t,aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\definecolor{mintedbackground}{rgb}{0.92,0.92,0.92}
\newmintedfile[javacode]{java}{bgcolor=mintedbackground,fontfamily=tt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Text is fine}
  Text
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Code has different top offset}
  \javacode{error.inc}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note, that the offset of the textslide ist identical. [image: left on ubuntu 16.04, right on debian 9]

The code generated by minted on both systems is

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PYG{n}{Hello}
\end{Verbatim}
```

which, intentionally, is rather easy.
The diffs of the generated code for default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle
 and default.pygstyle is shown here (diff -c0  ).

```
*** 21 ****
- \expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@vm\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
--- 20 ----
***************
*** 46 ****
- \expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@dl\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
--- 44 ----
***************
*** 55 ****
- \expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@fm\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
--- 52 ----
***************
*** 76 ****
- \expandafter\def\csname PYG@tok@sa\endcsname{\def\PYG@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
--- 72 ----

*** 21 ****
- \expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@vm\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
--- 20 ----
***************
*** 46 ****
- \expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@dl\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
--- 44 ----
***************
*** 55 ****
- \expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@fm\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
--- 52 ----
***************
*** 76 ****
- \expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@sa\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
--- 72 ----
```

Obviously, the name of the generated pyg differs, but the content is the same.

I am used to getting the same layout on LaTeX-Sources for ages, this really troubles me. Please nobody suggests to keep on one system only, that won't work for long and is the main reason I do not use other software for documents but LaTeX.

Thanks for any help or advice

Added both filelists as per request (div is too large), there are lots of different versions...

filelist.debian

```
  beamer.cls    2017/01/22 v3.40 A class for typesetting presentations
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
beamerbasemodes.sty    
beamerbasedecode.sty    
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
beamerbaseoptions.sty    
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2016/10/09 v1.0u Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2017/01/12 v0.06k Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
hyperref.sty    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    
beamerbasefont.sty    
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    
beamerbasetitle.sty    
beamerbasesection.sty    
beamerbaseframe.sty    
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    
beamerbaseframesize.sty    
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    
beamerbasecolor.sty    
beamerbasenotes.sty    
beamerbasetoc.sty    
beamerbasetemplates.sty    
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    
beamerbaseboxes.sty    
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    
beamerbasetheorems.sty    
 amsmath.sty    2016/11/05 v2.16a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2015/03/04 v2.20.2
beamerbasethemes.sty    
beamerthemedefault.sty    
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    
   babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2017/02/22 v2.0g Standard LaTeX file
  minted.sty    2016/10/31 v2.4.1 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX
 fvextra.sty    2016/09/02 v1.2.1 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvrb

  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
fancyvrb.sty    2008/02/07
 upquote.sty    2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verbat
im
textcomp.sty    2017/02/22 v2.0g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
  ts1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  lineno.sty    2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
  t1cmtt.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
shellesc.sty    2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
ifplatform.sty    2010/10/22 v0.4 Testing for the operating system
catchfile.sty    2016/05/16 v1.7 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
   error.w18
 xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
  framed.sty    2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
beamerthemeMadrid.sty    
beamercolorthemewhale.sty    
beamercolorthemeorchid.sty    
beamerinnerthemerounded.sty    
beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty    
  ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
```

filelist.ubuntu

```
  beamer.cls    2015/01/05 3.36 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revi
sion 8a39122e1f63)
beamerbasercs.sty    2015/03/08 (rcs-revision 368aa9ba9d38)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2013/09/03 (rcs-revision 768f2d98ca64)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2013/03/10 (rcs-revision 47431932db0d)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbasefont.sty    2015/01/05  (rcs-revision b4b4bee242e2)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2013/09/03  (rcs-revision a55719c41d85)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2013/12/25  (rcs-revision f6bd5e3805da)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2013/06/07  (rcs-revision 60b9fe0f342f)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2014/02/20  (rcs-revision 4b8ceeeff434)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2015/01/05  (rcs-revision 431510bb5890)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2013/10/18  (rcs-revision 5cf6c5555a45)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2015/02/21  (rcs-revision d944b04ee2d5)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2015/03/08  (rcs-revision 7270298bbaae)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2014/06/30  (rcs-revision 580088513a67)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2012/05/13  (rcs-revision 56972908a390)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2014/09/10  (rcs-revision 393f6dcff371)
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2015/02/27  (rcs-revision 923f4bf87efa)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
 amsmath.sty    2016/03/03 v2.15a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2015/03/04 v2.20.2
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2014/06/30  (rcs-revision 580088513a67)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
   babel.sty    2016/02/24 3.9q The Babel package
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2015/12/03 v1.1r UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2015/12/03 v1.1r UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2015/12/03 v1.1r UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2015/12/03 v1.1r UTF-8 support for inputenc
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
  minted.sty    2015/09/09 v2.1 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX
fancyvrb.sty    2008/02/07
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
ifplatform.sty    2010/10/22 v0.4 Testing for the operating system
catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
   error.w18
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
 xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
  lineno.sty    2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
  t1cmtt.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
_minted-error/default.pygstyle
beamerthemeMadrid.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemewhale.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemeorchid.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerinnerthemerounded.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty    2012/10/16  (rcs-revision 51a8c72084af)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
```

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` to your preamble and make a diff of the .log files? My guess would be some different package versions.

Comment: added both lists, there are lots of differences. Does that mean I won't get any help? I am afraid so. Thus, at the end of the day there is but doom? I found ways to prevent the other bugs (it was about the appearance of backslash in comments in imported code), any idea how I can fix the top offset despite the different package versions?

Comment: Can you try if the difference still happens when you use the same beamer version? Ideally I suggest to update both systems to current versions of the packages, but if you cannot do this, you can find the files for beamer v.3.40 (which you have on debian) here: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/tree/9f10a22b5c06012e14ad865579fc1ff9b84f5c96/base Can you try them on your ubuntu system?

Comment: checked it out and set TEXINPUTS to the base folder, got  

beamer.cls    2018/02/20 v3.50 A class for typesetting presentations

on the filelist, but still the same offset (thus no change on ubuntu)

Comment: mmm, then probably one of the other packages. My suggestion would be to use the same texlive version on both computers.

Comment: thanks a lot. OK, I was afraid of that after I have seen the many different versions. I'll stick to the ubuntu version for the time being and assume ubuntu 18.04 in winter will be based on debian 9 and that then the versions will be similar again (or use an ubuntu vagrant box for texing on debian [weird]). Of the problems the biggest remaining is the top offset, the rest is manageable. Any idea which packages sets the top offset and how?

Comment: with beamer rulled out my next best guess would be minted.

Comment: yep - the little devil. I copied over the minted.sty from the ubuntu system, and here we go. The diffs are massive (diff -c ... | grep wc reports 1417 lines) and I do not see where that happens; but just copying the minted.sty file does the trick. I check in the minted.sty in version control an declare the thing solved. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as caused by outdated package version

Comment: I tried to with: "Thanks to samcarter we could attribute it to different versions of the packages and for the top offset minted.sty. How exactly and why we don't know.". But it was deleted by an editor with the comment "This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. " If you want to write something that will pass the editor I am happy to accept it.

Comment: oh, so closing down means delete. also fine. Thus, few people seem to have problems with outdated package versions?

Comment: I think your answer is a good summary of the problem. I voted to have it undeleted, but unfortunately one vote is not enough. Putting the questions "on hold" (not close) with a customised reason, that the problem was caused by outdated package versions, is the text best thing to do to remove it from the list of unanswered questions.